# Access to dictionary value by tf.string tensor

Tags: python, tensorflow

I defined `preporcessing` functions for a `tensorflow` dataset like:

```
def tsv_atomic(mt): #preprocessor function
    def rel_preprocessor(ds):
        def to_inputs_and_targets(ex):
            rel = ex["prefix"]
            some_val = my_dict[rel]
            # ... the rest of preprocessor
```

And `mydict` is something like:

```
mydict = {"a": "string a", "b": "string b"}
```

however, it seems `rel` is a tensor and I can't use it as a key for my dictionary. How can I resolve this problem? Should I convert my dictionary to something else?

It's the class for creating the tensorflow dataset:

```
        def dataset_fn(split, shuffle_files=False):
            # We only have one file for each split.
            del shuffle_files

            # Load lines from the text file as examples.
            ds = tf.data.TextLineDataset(split_to_filepattern[split])
            # Split each "<question>\t<answer>" example into (question, answer) tuple.
            ds = ds.map(
                functools.partial(
                    tf.io.decode_csv,
                    record_defaults=["", "", ""],
                    field_delim="\t",
                    use_quote_delim=False,
                 #select_cols= sel_cols,
                ),
                num_parallel_calls=tf.data.experimental.AUTOTUNE,
            )
            # Map each tuple to a {"question": ... "answer": ...} dict.
            ds = ds.map(
                lambda *ex: dict(zip(["prefix","input_text","target_text"], ex))
                #functools.partial(to_inputs_and_targets, ex))
            )
```

The `ex` or examples are created in the code above.

Comment: why are you passing `ds` and `mt` as parameters if at the end you don't use them?

Comment: @SembeiNorimaki it's part of code from a framework. They call it for each row in dataset. I also added more code...

Comment: Please post some dummy data to reproduce your code. Right now it is difficult to do anything.